# Is it correct to say "he wrote a note of 'Mom, we are out of milk'"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

**A note** is "[a short piece of writing to help you remember something](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/note_1?q=note)".

I expect dictionaries will have some examples using the noun "**note**" with direct quote but they have none.

We have this sentence "[Dave made a note of her address and phone number.](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/note)" in the dictionary

Can we say something like this?

> **Dave made a note of "*25/4 Oxford Street; phone no: 9630253*"**

Is it correct to say:

> **he wrote a note of "*Mom, we are out of milk*"**

or

> **he wrote a note "*Mom, we are out of milk*"**

Comment: If you write a note to 'Mom', it is is not a note to help yourself remember something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Of" does not work in this situation, nor does any preposition.

Informally it would suffice to write *He wrote a note - "Mum we are out of milk".*

More formally you need to place something after "note" - such as *He wrote a note saying "Mum, we are out of milk"*

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a right way to write this. You have several options.  The word "of" doesn't seem to be required, so 'He wrote a note: "Get some milk."' is possible.  The punctuation could be a comma or a colon.

> Dave noted down her address, "25/4 Oxford street".

You could use the verb wrote as the quoting verb: 'He wrote, "Get some milk" in note.'

You can say 'He wrote a note which read, "Get some milk."'  You could use a participle "reading" instead of the relative clause

But it is probably usually better to report rather than quote:

> He wrote a note asking his mum to get some milk.

Answer (score -1):

The word "note" itself is a verb too. You should use it as:

> He noted in a note, "Mom, we're out of milk."

Or if noted anywhere else, it is better to write:

```
He noted, "Mom, we're out of milk."
```

When using it as a noun, you may write:

```
A note he wrote said, "Mom, we're out of milk."
```

Or

```
He wrote a note saying, "Mom, we're out of milk."
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problematic part of the OP's sentence. Moreover, there is no "should", only a 'can': "he wrote in a note" is perfectly fine.

Comment: "He noted" does not mean 'he wrote a note".